# How to reuse angular 4 component

Tags: angular, components, primeng, code-reuse

I'm using in my project some components from primeNG (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng). These components have its own properties and events.

I may customize these components sometime, so I'm creating my own components importing these components, but when accessing my components I can't use the properties and events of the primeng components.

Am I reusing the components correctly? How is the correct way to have reusable components in a Angular 4 project?

For better understanding:

I have a component called checkbox

.HTML

```
<div>
    <p-checkbox [ngModel]="check" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"  binary="true"></p-checkbox>
</div>
```

.TS

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',

})

export class CheckBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()  check: boolean;
  @Output() checkChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  onChange($event) {
      this.check = $event;
      this.checkChange.emit($event);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And I can reuse this way:

```html
<app-input-checkbox [(check)]="input.read">  </app-input-checkbox>
```

But I cannot use the primeng properties like disabled this way

```html
<app-input-checkbox [(check)]="input.read" [disabled]="true">  </app-input-checkbox>
```

How is the right way to use all properties from primeng?

App Module:

```js
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
// import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import {
  InputTextModule, CheckboxModule, DropdownModule,
  ToolbarModule, SpinnerModule,
  ButtonModule,
  AccordionModule,
  DialogModule,
  InputTextareaModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Shared Folder
import { NavBarComponent } from './shared/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { CheckBoxComponent } from './shared/input/checkbox/checkbox.component';
import { InputTextComponent } from './shared/input/text/text.component';


import { UserPermissionsComponent } from './components/user-permissions/user-permissions.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    InputTextComponent,
    CheckBoxComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    InputTextModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    DropdownModule,
    ToolbarModule,
    ButtonModule,
    AccordionModule,
    SpinnerModule,
    InputTextareaModule,
    HttpModule,
    DialogModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'administration',
        component: AccordionAdministrationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'permission',
        component: AccordionPermissionComponent
      }
    ]),
    FormsModule, // <-- import the FormsModule before binding with [(ngModel)]
    // NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Check your tags. Read all of their descriptions carefully

Comment: you can put the example code?

Comment: @alehn96 here is the code

Comment: you can put the app.module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 <app-input-checkbox [(check)]="input.read" [disabled]="true">  </app-input-checkbox>
```

with this

```
<app-input-checkbox [check]="input.read" (checkChange)="methodInParentComponent($event)" [disabled]="true">  </app-input-checkbox>
```

check is input property, you can not put [(check)] it is wrong, you define with output property the data that you want to pass a parent component.

Add to the component a input property disabled

```
@Input() disabled;
```

and add to the checkbox primeng component the property disabled

```
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="value" binary="true" [disabled]="disabled"> </p-checkbox>
```

Add to app.module

```
import {CheckboxModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

and in imports

```
imports: [..., CheckboxModule]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I thought that doing this the binding was working in two-way. But the question was about the disabled property. [disabled]=true is still not working.

Comment: So do I have to create my property for every property that I want to use in the primeng component?

Comment: If you want to customize your checkbox component yes, but usually you can to use the primeng component directly, not to do a wrapper component, use p-checkbox directly